# how to find out the existence of a file in system verilog

Tags: unix, system, verilog, system-verilog, uvm

I have a file *abc/xyz.log* in log directory. How can I find if the file exists or not in SystemVerilog class. If the file exists I want to delete the file.

Thanks.

Comment: I tried with    $system(if (-e $SCRIPTS_DIR/rank0_performance.log) then )
    $system(rm -rf $SCRIPTS_DIR/rank0_performance.log);

Comment: but it is giving me compilation error in cadence tool. can you pls give me the syntax

Comment: I was trying $system("if (-e $SCRIPTS_DIR/rank0_performance.log) then rm -rf $SCRIPTS_DIR/rank0_performance.log"); rank0_file = $fopen("scripts/rank0_performance.log", "a+"); but it looks it is not able to remove the file before opening. is this the correct way?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$fopen` and it returns 0 if it doesn't exist. If it does exist,  `$fclose` the file and then use `$system("shell command")` to delete it.

Comment: I was trying     $system("if (-e $SCRIPTS_DIR/rank0_performance.log) then rm -rf $SCRIPTS_DIR/rank0_performance.log");
    rank0_file = $fopen("scripts/rank0_performance.log", "a+");   but it looks it is not able to remove the file before opening. is this the correct way?

Comment: This is probably a tool specific problem in the way $system was implemented. You will need to contact your tool vendor.

Comment: Not the ideal answer. Some simulators (xcelium) will produce the following message in the log when $fopen fails:

`Open failed on file "file_does_not_exist". No such file or directory`

Comment: @edc, In that case `$fopen` should still return 0; it is not a fatal error.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Unix utility "test" (see "man test") through a $system call can do the job. It can also be done through direct C using the stat() function (much more cumbersome).  This example can be leveraged to do what you want. In this case it checks for the existence of a directory and it not found, attempts to create it.

```
string report_dir;
report_dir  = {SIM_ROOT,"/",PROJ_NAME,"/",TECH_PROCESS,"/",LOGNAME,"/doc/functional"};
if ($system($sformatf("/usr/bin/test -d %s", report_dir)) != 0) begin
     $display("INFO: creating output directory %s", report_dir);
     if($system($sformatf("mkdir -p %s", report_dir)) != 0) begin
        $display("ERROR: mkdir -p %s returned an error", report_dir);
        $fatal(0);
     end
end
if($system($sformatf("/usr/bin/test -d %s -o -w %s", report_dir, report_dir)) != 0) begin
     $display("ERROR: output directory %s does not exist or is not writeable", report_dir);
     $fatal(0);
end
```